# Fetch more than 16 private repos on free self hosted Sourcegraph

Tags: sourcegraph

I have installed self hosted sourcegraph version using Docker-compose :

https://docs.sourcegraph.com/admin/deploy/docker-compose

But it seems that I can't fetch more than 16 **private** repos (from Github, Gitlab.com or my self hosted Gitlab instance).

Is this the normal behaviour or is it something I can customize ?

Comment: Normal. It's a restriction that comes with the Free version of Sourcegraph Code Search.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought so but didn't manage to find any information in the docs.